# Intriguing moves with the $3\times3\times3$ Rubiks cube

Tags: combinatorics, logic, recreational-mathematics, coloring, combinatorial-proofs

### Preface

This is a recreational problem I kinda figured out during my free time playing around with the Rubik cube, so I hope everyone will take it as chilling as I did.

Okay, so for those of you who are yet familiar with the notation of movements in a $3\times3\times3$ cube, here's the reference: [image]

I mean it's easy to remember: just the initial of Up, Down, Left,  Right, Front, and Back for the clockwise movement and add the apostrophe to the counterclockwise movement.

Now on one beautiful day, I suddenly hate solving the cube normally and searched for different configurations, and I stumbled upon this problem:

**What is the optimal way to bring the cube to the state where no two adjacent square shares the same color?** $\tag{1}$

Now apparently one of the ways is to do $UU-DD-RR-LL-BB-FF$ and you get something like a 3D-checkerboard.

But now what if I require more delicacy than that, say: at least 3 colors per face?

I mean that's totally possible: I do $U-D'-R-L'-U-D'-R-L'$and yes! We get this very beautiful cube:
[image]

Now if you notice, what I did was I randomly move with $U-D', R-L'$and you can also add $B-F'$ if you want.

**My conjecture is, for the optimal move (which I mean you don't do U-U' continuously). Then for any scheme as described in $(1)$, the only optimal way to achieve it would be to rotate opposite faces of the Rubik in opposite directions.**

What do you think? Can it be proven or not?

Comment: For this type of patterns I always move the in-between layers. True, you do need to do a back-and-forth to physically do those (which is probably why the speed solvers shun them), but mathematically they are simpler to describe as moves affecting the middle layers only.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I mean ofc you can do the in between layers, which is why I had to do the formalisms above to ensure that every move is legitimately on the edges of the Rubik. I also acknowledge that the best move to solve ANY configuration is 20 moves, which in this case is way less cuz I use only 6 moves

Comment: So for me this pattern is 3 or 4 moves, depending on how you count. One quarter turn with the middle layer in z-direction, moving the red-green-red pattern to the face on the left. Then a half turn with with the middle layer in x-direction, after which we see an all yellow side facing us. Then a quarter turn with the middle layer in y-direction fixing the rest.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I said we don't do that here sir. Please don't count the middle layer that would definitely be the formalism. But hey, that's not even what the question is about

Comment: Indeed! I will think about it.